# UFW Blocking packets it shouldn't be

Tags: ubuntu, ufw

I saw a lot of other questions around this topic, but none of the issues those other people had seem to apply to my case. I have this ufw config:

```
23                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
32270                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
34088                      DENY        Anywhere                  
9091                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
plexmediaserver-all        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Samba                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
9200                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
9300                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5601                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       10.10.0.0/16              
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
23 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
32270 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
34088 (v6)                 DENY        Anywhere (v6)             
9091 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
plexmediaserver-all (v6)   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Samba (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
9200 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
9300 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5601 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

but for some reason my ufw logs look like this:

```
Jul 22 11:00:26 mini kernel: [426858.470272] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp2s0 OUT=br-aae4e8ac78a0 MAC=e0:d5:5e:9d:54:37:14:f6:d8:9e:17:09:08:00 SRC=10.10.0.153 DST=172.18.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=45918 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=43326 DPT=8080 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

My docker container listens to the correct address:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1962/docker-proxy   
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1969/docker-proxy
```

And my `iptables -xvnL | grep 8080` looks like this:

```
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:8080
```

This issue didn't exist until a few weeks ago. What happened? Is there anything I'm supposed to add to the config? Isn't this firewall config tool supposed to be "uncomplicated"?

Comment: UFW is just a wrapper around iptables. It is "uncomplicated" in configuration but not in debugging. You need to show your entire iptables. Please also note that the Docker documentation states the following: "Docker and ufw use iptables in ways that make them incompatible with each other."

Comment: sorry for the late reaction. This isn't a docker vs ufw issue, if I start a random netcat listener, I experience the same symptoms